# Who is supposed to message in this situation?

Tags: peer-review, journals, editors

I need to inquire about the expected date for the final decision as I sent the minor revisions since one month . should I message `Editor-in-Chief` or `Journals Editorial Office (JEO)`. what is the time expected between sending minor revision and the final decision in general, please ?

Comment: No matter who you ask, you are unlikely to get any firm answer. Like fruit, journals "pick" (finalize) papers when they are ripe. But ask anyone you have already corresponded with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, a person who works as a general manager or coordinator for the editorial office is most likely to be able to give you some updates or information. However, I do think this also varies by journal. But I generally default to whoever I was communicating most with, like Buffy mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, message the journal editorial office.

If you were mistaken and should have messaged the editor-in-chief instead, then the worst that can happen is the editorial office will forward your message to the editor-in-chief, potentially losing a day's worth of time (but not much more, since the editorial staff work full-time and will see and act on your message quickly). On the other hand, editor-in-chiefs are wont to delay longer, because they are busy people and are not likely to be work on the journal full-time.