# Who should I message for the status of a paper?

Tags: peer-review, journals, editors

I need to check the status of my paper. Should I message the Editor-in-Chief or the Journals Editorial Office (JEO)?

While Editor-in-Chief who sent to me the comments of the reviewers.

Will it be a problem if I send for both the same message for inquire the status ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/190035/who-is-supposed-to-message-in-this-situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that the status is on some public facing web page and that when it changes it will be updated fairly quickly.

I'd also expect that who you message at the editorial level won't really matter as you will most likely be answered by clerical staff using some boilerplate response that might be informative or not. Whoever you email will just pass the request to the journal's staff.

I'd also recommend not sending any message if it is just for informational purposes. If you have a real need to know, not just unease, then do so. But too much messaging by too many worried authors will slow down any process.

Comment: Thanks for the answering . I checked the status as i got minor revisions and sent it at 23/9  but didn't get any response yet